# Does the feature level affect multisampling?

Tags: directx, directx11, antialiasing

I'm using DirectX 11 with the feature level 9_3 even though my computer could run 11_0, but I want to support older hardware as well.

I'm using `CheckMultisampleQualityLevels` to check whether multi sampling with the given samplecount is supported or not. However it returns 1 for quality with 4samples. And with 8samples it returns 0 (so its not supported). With feature level 11_0 `CheckMultisampleQualityLevels` returns 1 for 8samples. I'm using a ***AMD/ATI Radeon HD5830***. In the most DirectX9 games I can still use 8x antialiasing. So why is it not supported in DX11 with a lower feature level.

Another point is it seems like 4samples doesnt really affect the output:
[image]

With mutlisampling disabled the result is the same. I'm sure that I configurated ms correctly.. even in the Depthbuffer.

Whether I enable `AntialiasedLineEnable` in the `RasterizerDesc` or not the output is still the same.

I searched in MSDN but I couldn't find any more information about multisampling.

EDIT: The blacklines in the picture are outlines made in the pixelshader

Answer (score 1):

A breakdown of capabilities by feature level is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll note there is no explicit mention of MSAA support. However, the [documentation does point out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476150%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ID3D11Device_CheckMultisampleQualityLevels) that for the 9.3 feature level, no guarantee is made for MSAA support.